# $X$ and $Y$ independent and uniform on $[0,1]$. Find PDF of $X+Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The idea here is to use convolution. The books does the following:

> Let $z=X+Y$. I have that 
>   $$f_Z(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Y(x-u)f_X(u) \ du.\tag 1$$
>
> First we note that the range of $Z$ is $[0,2],$ so we need to pick our
>   $x$ from that interval. Now $f_X(u)=1$ if $u$ is between $0$ and $1$
>   and $0$ otherwise. For the other factor in the integrand, note that
>   $f_Y(x-u)=1$ if its argument $x-u$ is between $0$ and $1$, that is
>   $\color{green}{0\le x-u \le 1}$, and $0$ otherwise. Since $x$ is fixed
>    and $u$ is the variable, we rewrite this as $\color{red}{x-1\le u \le
>  1}.$ Hence for any $x\in[0,2]$ the two inequalities
>
> $$0\le u\le 1 \quad  \text{and} \quad \color{brown}{x-1\le u\le x}\tag
>  2$$
>
> must be satisfied and if they are, the integrand equals $1$. We need
>   to distinguish between 2 cases:
>
> **Case 1:** $x\in[0,1].$ In this case, the two conditions in $(2)$ are satisfied if $0\le u \le x.$ Hence, for $0\le x \le 1$
>
> $$f_Z(x)=\int_0^xdu=x, \quad 0\le x\le 1.$$
>
> **Case 2:** $x\in[1,2]$. Here, the conditions are satisfied if $x-1\le u \le 1$, ad we get
>
> $$f_Z(x)=\int_{x-1}^1du=2-x, \quad 1\le x \le 2.$$

---

**Questions:**

1. I don't understand how they go from the green, to red to brown inequality. Is there a typo in the book?
2. I still don't understand the need to split this into two cases and how they came up with the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The inequalities come from simple equivalent transformations. E.g., $x-u\leq 1$, add $u-1$ to both sides, and then you obtain $x-1\leq u$.

You need to split into two cases because the relevant interval, where $f$ is nonzero, is $[0,1]$. The value of $f(x-u)$ and $f(u)$ depend on whether or not $x-u$ or $u$ is in or out of the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes but you did not explain how to go from $0 \le x-u\le 1$ to $x-1 \le u \le x$. Your example involves only one side.

Comment: That was intentional. The other one is equally trivial, so you should think about it.

Comment: How can I first do it on one side and then the other? I thought inequalities should be manipulated simultaniously. So If I add $u-1$ to left side, I should also add it to middle and right?

Comment: I see your confusion now. Think about the chain of inequalities as two separate statements. So from $0\leq x-u$ and $x-u\leq 1$, first show $x-1\leq u$ (in fact, I did that), and then show $u\leq x$. Then the two results can be combined into $x-1\leq u\leq x$.

Comment: Ahh, alright ok I see how this is trivial now. It seems to be a typo in the book. The red and brown inequalities should be the same. Also note that in case 2, they suddenly replace the farmost right $x$ with a $1$. Why?

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive view for the second question:

Consider the $x$-$y$ plane. The point $(x,y)$ is uniformly distributed over a square. For a fixed $u$, the equation $u=x+y$ specifies a $45^\circ$ line across the plane. The PDF of $u$ is thus proportional to the intersection length of the line with the square, which obviously is in two pieces, and piecewise linear.

Answer (score 1):

For identifying the case distinction of the ranges of the density of $X+Y$, a picture of the unit square would be most helpful to find the distribution function, as has been reiterated in several posts of this question here.

The algebra is purely mechanical.

First of all, the red part should read $x-1\le u\le x$, so that $(2)$ is clear.

But for a single range of $u$, $(2)$ is equivalent to saying $\max(x-1,0)\le u\le\min(x,1)$.

That means your final integration is of the form

\begin{align}
f_Z(x)&=\int_{\max(x-1,0)}^{\min(x,1)}\,du\,\mathbf1_{0<x<2}
\\
\\&=[\min(x,1)-\max(x-1,0)]\,\mathbf1_{0<x<2}
\end{align}

Naturally, you would have to break the range at $x=1$ and the result follows that $$f_Z(x)=x\,\mathbf1_{0<x<1}+(2-x)\,\mathbf1_{1<x<2}$$

Comment: Well the book first writes that $0\le x-1 \le 1$ can be rewritten as $$x-1\leq u \leq 1$$, which is the red text. So it should not be what you suggested according to the book, which is why I asked if it is a typo in teh book? If it is as you suggested, then how does one go about this? Also I have not learned indicator functions.

Comment: You have two inequalities: $0\le u\le 1$ and $0\le x-u\le 1$, where $0\le x\le 2$. The latter implies $x-1\le u\le x$ for $x\in[0,2]$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why $(2)$ is equivalent to $\text{max}(x-1,0)\le u \le \text{min}(x,1)?$

Comment: @Parseval If $x<a$ and $x<b$, then $x<\min (a,b)$. On the other hand, $x>c$ and $x>d$ is same as saying $x>\max(c,d)$. It is quite obvious and is often written just to club the bounds into a single bound.