# How is $0\le u\le 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \color{brown}{x-1\le u\le x}\Longleftrightarrow \max(x-1,0)\le u\le\min(x,1)?$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885110/x-and-y-independent-and-uniform-on-0-1-find-pdf-of-xy/2885142?noredirect=1#comment5957788_2885142) question yesterday. I now understand how (2) is formed but I'm still in the dark in how is $$0\le u\le 1 \quad  \text{and} \quad \color{brown}{x-1\le u\le x}\Longleftrightarrow \max(x-1,0)\le u\le\min(x,1)?$$

In StubbornAtom's answer he gives the bounds of the interal where max is below and min is above. Why is it like this and not the reverse?

Comment: What do you think the reverse would look like, and what would it say in words?

Comment: Not that it is necessary to write both bounds using max/min for your original problem. I used it so that both ranges of $u$ are taken into account simultaneously, and write the density in a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the lower bound.
Since $u\geq 0$ and $u\geq x-1$, then $u$ is above both quantities, i.e. $u\geq \max\{0, x-1\}$.

A similar argument holds for the upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to see that if, and only if :

$$ u \geqslant x-1 \quad \text{and} \quad u \geqslant 0 \ \Longleftrightarrow \ u \geqslant \max(x-1,0)$$

Indeed, if a number is greater than two others, it's greater than the max, and reciprocally. As well, we have :

$$ u \leqslant x \quad \text{and} \quad u \leqslant 1 \ \Longleftrightarrow \ u \leqslant \min(x,1)$$

Comment: I do know the difference, I'm editing.